# What does it mean that the metric is static?

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, metric-tensor, symmetry, definition

I'm reading the paper [Regular phantom black holes](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/0511109) where in page 2 (left column) the authors write that "the metric is static where $A(\rho)>0$".
Does anyone know what they mean with the notion of [static](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Static_spacetime)?

With the world static one usually means that the spacetime admits two Killing vector fields $k^{\mu}=(1,0,0,0)~, k^{\nu}=(0,0,0,1)$ so the metric does not depend on the time and azimuthal coordinate.

If $A(\rho)<0$ this would also hold, so i cannot understand the meaning of static.

Comment: An obvious example is the Schwarzschild geometry where it is static only outside the event horizon. Inside the horizon the Killing field is spacelike.

Comment: @JohnRennie could you please elaborate on that a bit more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A(\rho)>0$, then $\partial_t$ is a time-like Killing vector field (so the components of the metric are independent of the temporal coordinate $t$) and there are no spatiotemporal cross terms, and so the metric is static. On the other hand, if $A(\rho)<0$ then $\partial_t$ is a *space-like* Killing vector field (meaning that $t$ is a spatial coordinate) and the components of the metric are *not* independent of the temporal coordinate (which is now $\rho$), and so the spacetime is no longer static$^\dagger$.

$^\dagger$Strictly speaking, these facts alone do not imply that the spacetime is no longer static - it could be that we're simply using bad coordinates - but that's the essential content of the passage.

Comment: Ah, it was so obvious!!! Thank you so much!!!